# Stack Overflow logo weird styling in the top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, design, top-bar

In the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) header, the text "stackoveflow" is truncated near by the search text box and a minimal part of the text only displaying.

I'm using Google Chrome browser.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Confirmed, IE11/Win7Entx64

Comment: Figuring it out now, thanks for reporting!

Comment: A fix for this is going out in the next build. As I'm not sure that this is the only quirk introduced in that change, I'll leave it for a dev to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now, see [my answer on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374321/115866). Thanks for reporting it!